# Azure Data Factory, If Activity expression with array element

Tags: azure-data-factory

[image]

I have an array HeaderList with a list of names.  I have a look up activity to look at a CSV file header.  Then, I have a IF activity to compare the first element. the expression in If activity is like this:

```
@equals(activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.Prop_0,variables('HeaderList')[0])
```

That does not work.  If I change it to this:
@equals(activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.Prop_0,'XYZ'), then it works.  How do I reference an array element in expression?

Thanks

```
@equals(activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.Prop_0,variables('HeaderList')[0])
```

[image]

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error in the if condition activity. But when the pipeline is debugged, it did not throw any error. I have repro'd the same in my ADF environment. Below are the steps.

- Lookup activity is taken, and it refers to a csv file.
  [image]
- An array variable 'HeaderList' is taken and values for the variable is set using **set variables** activity.

[image]

- Then **If Condition** activity is taken and below expression is given as a dynamic content.

`@equals(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.prop_0,variables('HeaderList')[0])`

- The same error is produced.
  Error: **Cannot fit unknown into function parameter any**.
  [image]
- When pipeline is debugged, it did not throw any error. It is successful.
  [image]